# Why can't I verify the download of elementary OS?

Tags: download

I have downloaded the .iso file several times and followed the directions for verifying the download, but when I enter the command: "sha256sum elementaryos-5.1-stable.202002814.iso" Then I get: "sha256sum elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200814: No such file or directory"

Comment: Your command that's in quotes doesn't match the download name. That's `sha256sum elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200814.iso`. You also need to be in the correct directory when you do so. So, if it's in /Downloads, make sure you're in that folder before running the command. It should also be noted that the file name changes periodically, so if you have an older ISO and are just getting around to verifying it then it may have a different name like elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200706.iso. If that's the case, just download the newer .iso and verify against that.